# Squid domain block

Tags: proxy, squid, block

i want lo block some porn domains, i tried this squid configuraztion:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8  
acl loggedUser  proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl proxyUser external nt_group ProxyUser
acl pornDomains dstdomain "/etc/squid/porndomains.txt"

http_access deny !localnet
http_access deny !loggedUser
http_access deny pornDomains
http_access allow proxyUser
```

And this is my porndomains.txt:

```
youporn.com
```

During squid startup i get no errors or warning, but i still access to youporn.com.
This from access.log:

```
1342771140.754    283 10.0.0.95 TCP_REFRESH_MISS/200 11377 GET http://www.youporn.com/ admin DIRECT/31.192.116.24 text/html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put a `.` before your domains in the `porndomains.txt`.

You are blocking `yourporn.com`, not `www.youporn.com` or `whatever.youporn.com`. `.youporn.com` will block all of those.

Happy testing!